# Twitter stream not delivering to S3 in json format

Tags: python, amazon-s3, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to stream twitter data into AWS S3, however the stream data is not in json format:

S3 bucket does not use any compression. Firehose does not use any data transform. I'm getting the tweets, but they have no type. I need to the load the data into a pandas dataframe.

```
class TwitterStreamer():
    """
    Class for streaming and processing fetched tweets
    """
    def stream_tweets(self, fetched_tweets_filename, hash_tag_list):
        #This handles twitter authentication and connection to streaming API
        listener = TwitterListener(fetched_tweets_filename)
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(token_key, token_secret)

        stream = Stream(auth, listener)

        #filter stream
        stream.filter(track=hash_tag_list, languages=['en'])


#Create class to print tweet - inherits from StreamListener
class TwitterListener(StreamListener):
    """
    This is a basic listener class that just prints received tweets
    """
    def __init__(self, fetched_tweets_filename):
        self.fetched_tweets_filename = fetched_tweets_filename
    
    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = json.loads(data)
        if 'text' in tweet.keys():
                #print (tweet['text'])
                message_lst = [tweet['text'].replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' '),
                               str(tweet['created_at']),'\n']
                message = '\t'.join(message_lst)
                print(message)
        response = client.put_record(DeliveryStreamName=DeliveryStreamName,
                                                 Record={'Data': message})
                                                 
        print('Status: ' + json.dumps(response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']))
        try:
            #print(data)
            

            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
               tf.write(message)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('error:')
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #session = boto3.Session()
    #kinesis_client = session.client('firehose')
    client = boto3.client('firehose', 
                          region_name='us-east-1',
                          aws_access_key_id='',
                          aws_secret_access_key='' 
                          )
    #partition_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    
    hash_tag_list=['omicron']
    fetched_tweets_filename = 'tweets.json'
    DeliveryStreamName = 'twitter-delivery-stream'
    
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename, hash_tag_list)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.